# Scaling an SVG in CSS

Tags: css, svg, scaling

I have the following line in my stylesheet that calls my website logo.

```
.navbar__logo::before{
    content: url("../images/logo/logo.svg");}
```

How can I scale this down? I'm learning a bit about viewPort & viewBox but cant seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: shortcut css `zoom:0.8`

Answer (score 0):

After declaring a `viewBox` in your `svg` file, you should definitely give your `pseudo-element` explicit `width` and `height`:

```
.navbar__logo::before {
  content: url("../images/logo/logo.svg");
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Beyond that, if you wish to dynamically resize your `pseudo-element` and / or animate the scaling you can use `transform: scale()`:

```
.navbar__logo::before {
  content: url("../images/logo/logo.svg");
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```